# Why does Zeppelin fail with "mismatched input ';' expecting <EOF>" in %spark.sql paragraph?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, apache-zeppelin

I have built a parquet file from a csv.

In Zeppelin, I created a sql statement like:

```
%spark.sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS df;
CREATE TABLE df (
    date_time STRING
  , site_name STRING
  , posa_continent STRING
  , user_location_country STRING
  , user_location_region STRING
  , user_location_city STRING
  , orig_destination_distance DOUBLE
  , user_id STRING
  , is_mobile STRING
  , is_package STRING
  , channel STRING
  , srch_ci STRING
  , srch_co STRING
  , srch_adults_cnt INT 
  , srch_children_cnt INT
  , srch_rm_cnt INT
  , srch_destination_id STRING
  , srch_destination_type_id STRING
  , is_booking STRING
  , cnt INT
  , hotel_continentm STRING
  , hotel_country STRING
  , hotel_market STRING
  , hotel_cluster STRING)
USING parquet
OPTIONS (path "s3://hansprojekt/training_17000000pq")
```

As result I get an error:

```
mismatched input ';' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 23)
== SQL ==
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS df;
-----------------------^^^
CREATE TABLE df (
    date_time STRING
  , site_name STRING
  , posa_continent STRING
  , user_location_country STRING
  , user_location_region STRING
  , user_location_city STRING
  , orig_destination_distance DOUBLE
  , user_id STRING
  , is_mobile STRING
  , is_package STRING
  , channel STRING
  , srch_ci STRING
  , srch_co STRING
  , srch_adults_cnt INT 
  , srch_children_cnt INT
  , srch_rm_cnt INT
  , srch_destination_id STRING
  , srch_destination_type_id STRING
  , is_booking STRING
  , cnt INT
  , hotel_continent STRING
  , hotel_country STRING
  , hotel_market STRING
  , hotel_cluster STRING)
USING parquet
OPTIONS (path "s3://hansprojekt/training_17000000pq")
set zeppelin.spark.sql.stacktrace = true to see full stacktrace
```

I don't understand the problem. The csv was seperated with ','.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one SQL statement at a [paragraph](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/quickstart/explorezeppelinui.html#note-layout) (aka *code section*) in `%spark.sql` in Zeppelin.

So, this one line in one paragraph:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS df;
```

and the one in another `%spark.sql` paragraph.

```
CREATE TABLE df (
    date_time STRING
  , site_name STRING
  , posa_continent STRING
  , user_location_country STRING
  , user_location_region STRING
  , user_location_city STRING
  , orig_destination_distance DOUBLE
  , user_id STRING
  , is_mobile STRING
  , is_package STRING
  , channel STRING
  , srch_ci STRING
  , srch_co STRING
  , srch_adults_cnt INT 
  , srch_children_cnt INT
  , srch_rm_cnt INT
  , srch_destination_id STRING
  , srch_destination_type_id STRING
  , is_booking STRING
  , cnt INT
  , hotel_continentm STRING
  , hotel_country STRING
  , hotel_market STRING
  , hotel_cluster STRING)
USING parquet
OPTIONS (path "s3://hansprojekt/training_17000000pq")
```

---

`%spark.sql` [provides a SQL environment using Spark SQL](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/interpreter/spark.html#overview) (via [SparkSQLInterpreter](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/spark/SparkSqlInterpreter.java)).

If I'm *not* mistaken, when requested for a result `SparkSQLInterpreter` simply executes [SQLContext.sql](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/spark/SparkSqlInterpreter.java#L113-L118):

```
  // method signature of sqlc.sql() is changed
  // from  def sql(sqlText: String): SchemaRDD (1.2 and prior)
  // to    def sql(sqlText: String): DataFrame (1.3 and later).
  // Therefore need to use reflection to keep binary compatibility for all spark versions.
  Method sqlMethod = sqlc.getClass().getMethod("sql", String.class);
  rdd = sqlMethod.invoke(sqlc, st);
```

That points at [SQLContext.sql](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@sql(sqlText:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) as the "execution environment".

> **sql(sqlText: String): DataFrame** Executes a SQL query using Spark, returning the result as a DataFrame.

And `sql` expects a single SQL statement.